# Lex parsing without spaces

Tags: c++, shell, yacc, lex

I am coding a custom shell using Lex, Yacc, and C++. It is being run in a Unix environment. It currently works fine as long as there are spaces between the tokens. for example:

```
ls | grep test > out
```

will pass:

```
WORD PIPE WORD WORD GREAT WORD
```

to Yacc, and then actions are taken from there. However, I need it to work when there are not spaces as well. for example:

```
ls|grep test>out
```

should work the same as the previous command. However, it currently only passes:

```
WORD WORD
```

is there a way to parse the input before Lex tokenizes it?

**Edit:**

Here is my Lex file:

```
%{

#include <string.h>
#include "y.tab.h"

%}

%%

\n  {
    return NEWLINE;
}

[ \t]   {
    /* Discard spaces and tabs */
    }   

">" { return GREAT; }

">&" { return GREATAMPERSAND; }

">>" { return GREATGREAT; }

">>&" { return GREATGREATAMPERSAND; }

"<" { return LESS; }

"|" { return PIPE; }

"&" { return AMPERSAND; }

[^ \t\n][^ \t\n]*  {
    /* Assume that file names have only alpha chars */
    yylval.string_val = strdup(yytext);
    return WORD;
}

.   {
    /* Invalid character in input */
    return NOTOKEN;
}

%%
```

Comment: You need to show your lex file in order for us to help you. You must have misdefined a token somewhere to get this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your definition of a `WORD`. Right now, when it encounters an alphabetic character, it considers everything up to the next whitespace as part of that `WORD`.

You want to change that so it doesn't include any of the punctuation you're using for other purposes:

```
[^ \t\n\>\<\|\&]+  {
    /* Assume that file names have only alpha chars */
    yylval.string_val = strdup(yytext);
    return WORD;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. WORD was including the pipes and other special characters.
I changed it to

```
[^\|\>\<\& \t\n][^\|\>\<\& \t\n]*  {
    yylval.string_val = strdup(yytext);
    return WORD;
}
```

and now it works.